# Two-loop renormalization Peskin and Schroeder

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, singularities

In section 10.5 of Peskin and Schroeder, Peskin and Schroeder says the value of the last diagram in (10.51) is just a constant, which we can freely adjust to absorb any divergent terms that are independent of the external momenta.

[image]

My question is: Doesn't this mean that we still have an infinity in our scattering cross section? Doesn't it need to be cancelled by something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a renormalizable theory all momentum-dependent divergences in diagrams one to three in the diagram are cancelled by diagrams four and five. Had this not been the case the theory would not be renormalizable and we would have to introduce counter-terms with additional derivatives.

Comment: What about momentum independent divergences?

Comment: Those can be completely absorbed by the last diagram.

Comment: While then the last diagram would still be infinite?

Comment: The last diagram is equal to $-i \delta_\lambda$, you can choose $\delta_\lambda$ to cancel all the momentum-independent divergences of the previous diagrams. It's similar to something like $$\lim_{\Lambda \to \infty} \Lambda - f(\Lambda)$$ and choosing $f(\Lambda) = \Lambda$ such that the whole expression vanishes.

Comment: Hi, may I ask why we could freely adjust the last diagram? I thought it's already been specified by one-loop renormalization, i.e. $-i\delta_\lambda=(-i\lambda)^2[-iV(4m^2)-2iV(0)]$. So isn't this already been specified?

Comment: It's fixed up to order $\lambda^2$ at one-loop, the two loop diagrams contribute an order $\lambda^3$ term to the counterterm.